# Delete a Node which is multiple of a given number with recursion [C programming]

Tags: c, list, recursion, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm finding troubles trying to implement a function, this is what the program should do:
The user must first input an integer number (this number is not added to the list).
Then, I have to write a function which deletes recursively all the nodes in the list that are multiple of the input number.

This is my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define true 1 
#define false 0
#define bool int

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next; 

} Node;

void addToHead(Node **head, int value);
void printList(Node *head);
bool isMultipleOf(int value, int n);
void deleteMultipleOfNNodes(Node **head, int n);


int main() {
    // Create head 
    Node *head = NULL;

    int loop = true;
    int input;

    // The value whose multiples must be deleted from the list
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    while (loop) {
        scanf("%d", &input);

        // End loop - print list
        if (input < 0) {
            deleteMultipleOfNNodes(&head, n);
            printList(head);
            loop = false;
        } else {
        // Add value to the head
            addToHead(&head, input);
        }

    }
    return 0;
}


void addToHead(Node **head, int value) {
    Node *temp;

    if (*head != NULL) { 
        // Create new node
        Node *newNode = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
        // Set new node data
        newNode -> data = value;
        // New node links to the head
        newNode -> next = *head;
        // New node is now the head of the list
        *head = newNode;

    } else {
        // Create head
        *head = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
        // Set head data
        (*head) -> data = value;
        // Head links to NULL
        (*head) -> next = NULL;

    }
}

void printList(Node *head) {
    Node *temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        if (temp -> next != NULL) {
            printf("%d -> ", temp->data);
        } else {
            printf("%d -> NULL", temp -> data);
        }
        temp = temp->next; 
    }

}

bool isMultipleOf(int value, int n) {
    // While the value is greater than zero, keep on subtracting the number
    while (value > 0) { 
        value -= n; 
    }

    return (value == 0);

}

void deleteMultipleOfNNodes(Node **head, int n) {
     // ========= CODE ================
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Hey man :), we can’t give you the answer (you won’t learn like this). Try to do some code and bring us what you did and what are the errors. It will be better for you for learning

Comment: Yes, I know but I've been struggling with the code for hours and thought a help would clear my head definitely ahaha. :)

Answer (score 1):

The function can look very simple

```
void deleteMultipleOfNNodes( Node **head, int n )
{
    Node *tmp = *head;

    if ( tmp != NULL )
    {
        tmp->data % n == 0 ? ( *head ) = ( *head )->next, free( tmp ) 
                           : ( void )(  head = &( *head )->next );
        deleteMultipleOfNNodes( head, n );
    }
}
```

Pay attention to that this function

```
bool isMultipleOf(int value, int n) {
    // While the value is greater than zero, keep on subtracting the number
    while (value > 0) { 
        value -= n; 
    }

    return (value == 0);

}
```

is invalid in general case because either value or n can be negative.

So define the function like

```
bool isMultipleOf( int value, int n ) 
{
    return value % n == 0;
}
```

In this case the function above can be rewritten like

```
void deleteMultipleOfNNodes( Node **head, int n )
{
    Node *tmp = *head;

    if ( tmp != NULL )
    {
        isMultipleOf( tmp->data, n ) ? ( *head ) = ( *head )->next, free( tmp ) 
                                     : ( void )(  head = &( *head )->next );
        deleteMultipleOfNNodes( head, n );
    }
}
```

The function `addToHead` is too complicated. It can be written the following way

```
bool addToHead(Node **head, int value) 
{
    Node *newNode = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );
    bool success = newNode != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        newNode -> data = value;
        newNode -> next = *head;
        *head = newNode;
    }

    return success;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program. It contains only those functions that are required to demonstrate the recursive function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next; 

} Node;

bool addToHead(Node **head, int value) 
{
    Node *newNode = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );
    bool success = newNode != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        newNode -> data = value;
        newNode -> next = *head;
        *head = newNode;
    }

    return success;
}

bool isMultipleOf( int value, int n ) 
{
    return value % n == 0;
}

void deleteMultipleOfNNodes( Node **head, int n )
{
    Node *tmp = *head;

    if ( tmp != NULL )
    {
        isMultipleOf( tmp->data, n ) ? ( *head ) = ( *head )->next, free( tmp ) 
                                     : ( void )(  head = &( *head )->next );
        deleteMultipleOfNNodes( head, n );
    }
}

void printList( const Node *head )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        printf( "%d --> ", head->data );
    }

    puts( "NULL" );
}

int main(void) 
{
    Node *head = NULL;
    const int N = 10;

    for ( int i = N; i != 0; i-- )
    {
        addToHead( &head, i );
    }

    printList( head );

    deleteMultipleOfNNodes( &head, 2 );

    printList( head );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 4 --> 5 --> 6 --> 7 --> 8 --> 9 --> 10 --> NULL
1 --> 3 --> 5 --> 7 --> 9 --> NULL
```